# Can we get an analytical solution to this equation involving the Lambert W function?

Tags: analysis, approximation, analyticity, lambert-w

Can we get an analytical solution to the variable $t$:
$$H\left(1+W\left(A\exp\left(Bt\right)\right)\right)=1+W\left(X\exp\left(Yt+Z\right)\right)$$
$W(x)$ is the Lambert W function.$A$ $B$ $X$ $Y$ $Z$ $H$ are all constant and positive.

What about the approximate solution? The $t$ is a positive real number.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y=1+W(A\exp(Bt)$, then $A\exp(Bt)=(y-1)\exp(y-1)$
You can find $t$ as a function of $y$, and put that into the right-hand side.
$H(y)=1+W(...)$

Comment: Sorry,I forgot to say that H is also constant.Thank you for your fast reply.But I can't understand clearly.I just want to get an answer like t=....Could this be possible?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that.  No, I can't think of a way.